# Using JavaScript comparison operators with current time

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an HTML table that should hide certain parts according to the time using JavaScript, for example;

> 6:30
> 6:45
> 7:05
>
> When the current time is equal or greater than 6:30 the first cell should hide.

The way I start this is;

> var now = new Date(); // to create date object
> var h = now.getHours(); // to get current hour
> var m = now.getMinutes(); // to get current minute

And then later;

> if (h>=6 && m>=30) {
> $('table#truetable tr:first').hide();
> }

This does not work (I think the problem is in the last part), as it wouldn't hide this (first) cell in let's say 7:25 as the minute number then isn't greater than 30, which means this way wouldn't work in many other cases.

Can I fix this? Do I need to do it another way?

Comment: What do you mean _"I think"_? Did you put `console.log(h); console.log(m)` to see the values???

Comment: I saw the values, they are identical to the current time in 24h format, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare by minutes:

```
if( h*60+m/*h:m*/ >= 6*60+30/*6:30*/ ){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to handle the case when it's 6 o'clock separately:

```js
if (h > 6 || (h == 6 && m >= 30)) {
  // Modify DOM
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function to convert a time in the `hh:mm` or `hh:mm:ss` format to seconds. You can find it below:

```
function hourConvert(str) {
    //this separates the string into an array with two parts, 
    //the first part is the hours, the second the minutes
    //possibly the third part is the seconds
    str = str.split(":"); 

    //multiply the hours and minutes respectively with 3600 and 60
    seconds = str[0] * 3600 + str[1] * 60;

    //if the there were seconds present, also add them in
    if (str.length == 3) seconds = seconds + str[2];

    return seconds;
}
```

It is now easy to compare times with each other:

```
if (hourConvert(str) > hourConvert("6:30")) //Do Stuff
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/TsEdv/1/

Comment: links are not answers. Please write your answer here, not somewhere else. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var t = new Date()
undefined
t.getHours()
20
t.getHours()>=6
true
h = t.getMinutes()
51
t>=30
true
```

This does work. your problem is that you are checking for time and minutes, which mean that if the minutes are lesser than 30 it will return false.

Your if translates to:

```
any hour bigger than six whose minutes are also bigger than 30
```

Your if condition should be:

```
if(h>=6 && m>=30 || h>=7)
```

or with numbers only

```
if(h*60+m>= 390)
```